# Contentful: How to get an entry using nothing but one of its fields? Or, how to set the entryId in web app?

Tags: contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api

I am needing to make some sharable blog post URLs. To do that, the URL must be something like webpage.com/blog-post-title.  It cannot be webpage.com/5GFd5GDSg2345WD.

Since I am using dynamic routing, I need to get a Contentful entry using nothing but what is on the URL. There should not be any queries because queries are ugly and reduce shareability, like webpage.com/blog-post-title?query=queriesAreUgly.

Unfortunately, I need the entryId to get the entry.  Also unfortunately, the entryIds are all very ugly and therefore completely useless/unusable.  I wish I could set my own entryId, but this does not appear to be possible for mysterious reasons.

I could make a lookup table that pairs URLs with entryIds, but I'm going to be handing this contentful project to someone who is not tech savy, and they should not have to manage a lookup table.

I could get all blog entries then filter by blog title, but, very obviously, this is inefficient, as I would be loading thousands of lines of text for no reason at all.

I could create my own backend API and doing all this myself, but this is also a bad solution because it would take too much time and I could not give it to my non-tech-savvy client.

There are seemingly no solutions to this problem which created by Contentful's inherent needless inflexibility.

The only efficient way to get this to work is to find the entry not by its ID but by one of its fields.  Is there a performant/efficient way to do this, or am I just going to have to filter through every single blog post until I find the one with the correct title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding a 'slug' field to the blog post content type, which you can auto-generate from the title using the field settings (so you don't have to type it out manually?)

[image: A screenshot showing the slug field options that can generate its value from the title field]

You can then filter on the slug field in the query.

If you're using the JavaScript SDK (which it sounds like you are), you can use `getEntries()` and filter by the slug field to get a single blog post. Like so:

```
import { createClient } from "contentful";

const client = createClient({
  space: {SPACE_ID},
  accessToken: {ACCESS_TOKEN},
});

const response = await client
  .getEntries({
    content_type: "blogPost",
    limit: 1,
    "fields.slug": "blog-post-title",
  })
  .then((entry) => entry)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thank you a ton for answering this.  I was not aware that I could use use filters to get one entry using "getEntries".  My assumption was that "getEntries" was only for getting multiple entries, while "getEntry" was only for getting one entry, and I suppose this assumption ended up being false.